# Can't change resolution to 1680x1050 on Windows 8.1 PC

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, resolution

My GPU is an AMD Radeon HD 7790, which I've used for a while but my PC crashed earlier and since rebooting I cannot get Windows to run in 1680x1050; there is no option for it either in Screen Resolution (from right click on desktop > screen resolution) or via AMD CCC. The highest I can get is 1600x1200.

My Monitor is a ViewSonic VA2216w (1680x1050) and I'm using Windows 8.1 64bit.

I've tried updating drivers, reinstalling CCC, rebooted PC a few times, nothing happens.

[Should also mention that I appear to have 2 monitors in Screen Resolution window which I don't actually have and have no idea where it came from...](http://puu.sh/jaiAL/fbc1541980.png)

Please help!

Comment: Did you reinstall CCC after a simple uninstall, or wipe it completely after uninstall with a program like Driver Sweeper?

Comment: simple uninstall, shall I try Driver Sweeper?

Comment: Yes try Driver Sweeper and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Reseat the cable from your computer going to your monitor (vga, dvi, display port, whatever the type) on each end. If there is a cable nearby, switch them out and see if it still has the issue.

Comment: unfortunately not the problem :(